# ABCpdf not rendering Font-Awesome

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome, gecko, abcpdf

We build a web application in C# .net 4.5 and used Font-Awesome for graphics font. But when it's time to render the page with ABCpdf and Gecko engine, the font is not redenring. We try to not installed the font on the servers for publish purposes. We are using ABCpdf8.

We try the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7523746/658129 and it's working but just if the font is installed on the server. We don't want to install the font on the server. We tried the method AddFont and EmbedFont with the physical path to the ttf font file but no success with this.

Anyone already have this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the current release of ABCpdf (11 or higher) as this supports Font-Awesome.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: This answer is no longer true; starting with version 11 of ABCpdf, Font-Awesome is supported.

When `AddImageHTML` or `AddImageURL` is used, ***NO*** fonts except those installed on the server are available. Only HTML Styled Text used with `AddHTML` takes notice of fonts added with `AddFont` or `EmbedFont`.  And HTML Styled Text is not real HTML; there is no CSS processing.

See my question from last year: [Using @font-face with ABCPDF? Or other way of getting fonts into PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020072/using-font-face-with-abcpdf-or-other-way-of-getting-fonts-into-pdf)